# J2EE preview error with javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsf

Trying to start an Eclise Maven Web-Project in J2EE preview server (in Glassfish4, it works fine) i get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
```

Howewer, trying to make the fix like adviced on some another topik in this forum:
set in properties->project->fasets-> user library the jsf-api-2.1,jar
(as external jar, what is not nice),
i get another error :

```
Started ServerConnector@1727e0ec{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet
```

Searching for solution i found the info, that this is caused by classes in 
javaee-web-api what are just blueprints and server must have implementaion for them.
That is why for example you write maven dependency for that as provided, like:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

So i guess it is in this external jar too, it just not suppose to be included. What jar must i add then to fix this problem, or there is another better solution for this?

Comment: just making hello-world tutorial and check that this runs everywhere fine, else is somethingwrong defined there

Answer (score 0):

you can add below dependency into project `pom.xml`
 and try to update the project.'

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

or you can also add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
2017-08-07 06:43:06.501:WARN:oejshC.JEETutorials:main: unavailable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.